# Erro OutOfMemoryError ao baixar lista de objetos

Tags: java, android

Estou com este erro ao baixar um objeto do webservice que possui imagens que estão convertidas na base64. A questão é que se esse objeto ja estiver salvo no banco de dados local do android o app funciona, consigo carregar muitos objetos ao mesmo tempo e mostrar na tela, mas agora estou baixando do webservice esses objeto, baixo um por um, e alguns estão dando este erro devido a quantidade de imagens que eles tem.

Não entendo porque se esses objetos quando ja estão no celular a memória não estoura, agora quando faço download acontece isso.

Isso acontece apenas no emulador do android na versão 2.3. nas superiores funcionam normal. Posso até baixar um array com todos os objetos e suas imagens.

**Método responsável por fazer o download**

```
public class Sincronismo {

    public static String GET(Context context, String endereco){
        //Verifica se existe conexão com a internet
        if(!existeConexao(context))
            return K.FALHA_CONEXAO;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String result = K.FALHA;
        try{

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(endereco);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            if(inputStream!=null)
                result = inputStreamParaString(inputStream);
            else
                result = K.FALHA;
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String inputStreamParaString(InputStream in) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line="";
        String result="";
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            result += line;

        in.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Este é o método que faz o download, deixo aqui para analizarem

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54247/discussion-on-question-by-skywalker-erro-outofmemoryerror-ao-baixar-lista-de-obj)

Answer (score 3):

**Se você tem uma imagem de alta resolução, você deve diminui-los. Consulte o tópico sob Down numa versão reduzida na memória.**

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620843/out-of-memory-error-android

**Sobre a forma de evitar esses erros:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151719/how-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-while-using-bitmap-in-android

**Para um aprofundamento:**

http://blogs.innovationm.com/android-out-of-memory-error-causes-solution-and-best-practices/

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

**Font:**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682672/android-out-of-memory-error-when-using-bitmaps

Comment: Bom, estou seguindo essas dicas, mas o problema que ainda tenho que tomar cuidado ao enviar imagens grandes. Na verdade elas nem viram bitmap  ja guardo direto no bd, apenas recebo em Base64 converto e salvo.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque  `android:largeHeap="true"` no seu *manifest*.

Comment: Obrigado @franM mas estive lendo sobre o `android:largeHeap="true"` e ele não funciona nas versões 2.3, justamente na que da problema